# Showing an ideal is not equal to $\Bbb Z[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

> Let $p = 4m + 1$ and $t = (2m)!$. Consider the ideal $I = (p, t + i)$ of $\Bbb Z[i]$ generated by $p$ and $t + i$. Show that $I$ is not equal to $\Bbb Z[i]$.

I started by trying to show that I is not principal.
Suppose (p, t + i) = (d) is a principal ideal. Then d divides both p and t + i, which means that d = 1 and then I = Z[i]. Then there exists a,b in Z[i], $a = a_0+a_1i$ and $b=b_0+b_1i$, such that $ap+(t+i)b=1$. I then got
$$(a_0p+b_0t-b_1)+(a_1p+b_1t+b_0)i=1$$
and so $a_0p+b_0t-b_1=1$.

I'm not sure how to continue to show that I is not principal.

Comment: *Every* ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is principal; so proving $I$ is not principal can't work.

Answer (score 3):

$I=\Bbb Z[i]$ if and only if $1\in I$. Then write $1=(a_0+a_1i)p+(b_0+b_1i)(t+i)$ as you already did. From $$(a_0p+b_0t-b_1)+(a_1p+b_1t+b_0)i=1$$ you get $a_0p+b_0t-b_1=1$ *and* $a_1p+b_1t+b_0=0$. Multiplying the last relation by $t$ and plugin $b_0t$ into the first one you get $m,n\in\Bbb Z$ such that $mp+n(t^2+1)=1$, that is, $\gcd(p,t^2+1)=1$. If $p$ is prime, then $p\mid t^2+1$ (**why?**) and this is a contradiction.

If $p$ is not prime, then there is no contradiction since a prime factor of $p$ is $\le 2m$, so it is a divisor of $(2m)!$ and therefore $\gcd(p,t^2+1)=1$. In this case $I=\Bbb Z[i]$: there exist $u,v\in\Bbb Z$ such that $pu+(t^2+1)v=1$, so $pu+(t+i)(t-i)=1$.

**Remark.** This proof shows that $$(p,t+i)=\Bbb Z[i] \mbox{ if and only if } \gcd(p,t^2+1)=1.$$ This can also be seen by showing that there is an isomorphism $$\Bbb Z[i]/(p,t+i)\cong\Bbb Z/(p,t^2+1).$$